# Component disappears randomly in the SOUTH position when using BorderLayout and pack()

Tags: java, swing, border-layout

I have a rather mysterious problem when using BorderLayout. When I place a JButton in the CENTER position and a component (say JLabel) in the SOUTH, the latter one disappears randomly. Here is an example. To see the problem you'll have to resize the window to a larger size and then move your mouse cursor all over the screen a bit (on an off the button, label, window title bar, Windows Taskbar, edges of the screen). You don't need to press the button. After a few seconds of such movements the label disappears. It only reappears if you resize or minimize/restore the window again.

The strange thing is, pack() seems to be important, I don't observe the problem in I use e.g. setSize(600,300) on my JFrame instead. Also it seems that the CENTER component must be a JButton, while the SOUTH component can be anything (I tried JLabel, JCheckBox), and the positions (SOUTH and CENTER) are important. Does not happen if the button is placed NORTH, for example.

It would be easy to avoid this situation in practice, of course, but still I would like to know why it happens, and whether I did anything wrong or unsafe. I am using JDK 8 release 77 on Windows 10.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;  

public class MyExample extends JFrame{
 MyExample() { initGUI();} // Constructor

 private void initGUI(){
  // Create the button
  JButton myButton=new JButton("Press ME !"); 

  // Create the label
  JLabel testLabel=new JLabel("TEST !!!");

  // Set up the window 
  JPanel pane=(JPanel) getContentPane();
  pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  pane.add(myButton,BorderLayout.CENTER);
  pane.add(testLabel,BorderLayout.SOUTH); 

  setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  pack();   
  // setSize(600,300);  

 }

 public static void main(String[] args){
  EventQueue.invokeLater(()->{
   MyExample me=new MyExample();
   me.setVisible(true);
  });  
 }
}
```

Note: I defined the JPanel object pane for clarity, but if I simply write instead

```
  // Set up the window 
  add(myButton,BorderLayout.CENTER);
  add(testLabel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

the result is exactly the same.

Comment: I had the same problem once, I simply updated my Java version and the problem was fixed.

Comment: Possibly a problem with Java's internals

Comment: @Winter Roberts 

Thanks for your answer. I have just updated JDK and JRE to 8u92, or rather made a clean install. However, nothing has changed, the SOUTH label still disappears.

Comment: @AlexeiGrechnev: works fine on current Mac OS X with the same JDK.

Comment: I've just tested with my 8u92 install, no problem.